# regex to match more than one occurrence of ; between any two random words Google sheets

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets

I am trying to create a regex to match more than one occurrence of `;` between two words (more than one letter).

Ex

`MM ZZ ; ; ; ; NN GGG ; ;  SSS. ;`

I need to replace `; ; ; ;` and  `; ;` with `;` so I would have

`MM ZZ;NN GGG;SS. ;`

If my string looks like `ZZ ; ; ; ; NN. ;` I managed to get `(?<=[a-zA-z])\b(.*)(?=[a-zA-z])\b` which works

But if my string is more complicated like `MM ZZ ; ; ; ; NN GGG ; ;  SSS. ;` then it does not work

How to do this?

Comment: Show the complicated string that it doesn't work for

Comment: sorry, added it

Comment: LIke this? `(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s*;\s;[\s;]*(?=[a-zA-Z])` https://regex101.com/r/S1VMuJ/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s*;\s;[\s;]*(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=[a-zA-Z])` Positive lookbehind, assert a char a-zA-Z to the left
- `\s*;\s;` Match at least 2 times `;` between optional whitespace chars
- `[\s;]*` Match optional whitespace chars or `;` chars
- `(?=[a-zA-Z])` Positive lookahead, assert a char a-zA-Z to the right

And replace with a single `;`

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/S1VMuJ/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s*;\s;[\s;]*(?=[a-zA-Z])/g;
const s = `MM ZZ ; ; ; ; NN GGG ; ;  SSS. ;
ZZ ; ; ; ; NN. ;
MM ZZ ; ; ; ; NN GGG ; ;  SSS. ;`;
console.log(s.replace(regex, ';'))
```

---

If the single semicolons should be separated by at least a single whitespace char:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s+(?:;\s+)+(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

In this pattern, this part `\s+(?:;\s+)+` matches 1+ whitespace chars, and repeats 1+ times `;` and 1+ whitespace chars.

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/VSFq2w/1)

Comment: Sorry but I think your expression is not satisfactory. He needs the expression to match all ";" characters. (including blanks), which are ONLY between a group of TWO letters. no more. Your expression matches with any group of letters (regardless of the number)

Comment: @MedOkl Where do you read `between a group of TWO letters` ? The question states `between two words (more than one letter).` and note that the OP also matches a single character with the character class `[a-zA-z]` (which should be `[a-zA-Z]`) And then the pattern will be `(?<=[a-zA-Z]{2})\s*;\s;[\s;]*(?=[a-zA-Z]{2})` to match 2 times a semicolon.

Comment: I must have read wrong. It's not that I read that. But I seemed to have seen it from his example result. Sorry, I will delete my answer